# Improve speed of mySQL Query with subquery and LIMIT/OFFSET

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to improve the speed of my query. It takes 30 seconds to load even though I have LIMIT it to 12. I am using subquery to get all the companies that are using the current selected data and order it by highest count of company. Here is my query below. And if I add a specific query. Example query=test It is more faster.

```
$get_query = isset($_REQUEST['query']) ? $_REQUEST['query'] : '';           
$get_all_vendors = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT tbl1.ID 
AS vendor_id, tbl1.post_title AS vendor_name,

(SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_companies
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts tbl2 

LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as tbl3 ON tbl2.ID=tbl3.post_id AND tbl3.meta_key = 'vendor-ap'           
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as tbl4 ON tbl2.ID=tbl4.post_id AND tbl4.meta_key = 'vendor-as'
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as tbl5 ON tbl2.ID=tbl5.post_id AND tbl5.meta_key = 'vendor-data'
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as tbl6 ON tbl2.ID=tbl6.post_id AND tbl6.meta_key = 'vendor-management'
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as tbl7 ON tbl2.ID=tbl7.post_id AND tbl7.meta_key = 'vendor-sr'
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as tbl8 ON tbl2.ID=tbl8.post_id AND tbl8.meta_key = 'vendor-ae'

WHERE (tbl2.post_type = 'company-stacks' 
AND tbl2.post_status = 'publish')
AND tbl3.meta_value LIKE CONCAT('%\"',tbl1.ID, '\"%')
OR tbl4.meta_value LIKE CONCAT('%\"',tbl1.ID, '\"%') 
OR tbl5.meta_value LIKE CONCAT('%\"',tbl1.ID, '\"%') 
OR tbl6.meta_value LIKE CONCAT('%\"',tbl1.ID, '\"%') 
OR tbl7.meta_value LIKE CONCAT('%\"',tbl1.ID, '\"%') 
OR tbl8.meta_value LIKE CONCAT('%\"',tbl1.ID, '\"%') ) AS featured_stackies

FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts tbl1 
WHERE tbl1.post_type = 'vendor-stacks' 
AND tbl1.post_status = 'publish' 
AND tbl1.post_title LIKE '%".$get_query."%'

GROUP BY tbl1.ID ORDER BY featured_stackies DESC LIMIT 12 OFFSET 0", OBJECT);

echo '<pre>';
    print_r($get_all_vendors);
echo '</pre>';
```

Right Now I have the total of 290 rows in the database.

**Updated**
I think the causing of slow loading of query is the `ORDER BY featured_stackies`

Comment: The causes are manifold. One cause is the fact that '%...' cannot use an index

Comment: @Strawberry Yes! I tried to add a static id with percentage. Ex. %170% It run fast. This is the main issue. I am trying to get the ID with double quotation. so I tried Concat function. How can I get that? It should be %"170"%

Comment: You're missing my point. Try to structure your data such that the opening wildcard (%) isn't required

Answer (score 1):

As per the MySQL architecture and speed optimization principles

a `JOIN` query as sub query is not a good practice

try to directly join in main query

You current query is trying to do

[image]

table `posts` and `postmeta` are being joined with six joins, bring it as part of the main query, reason being that main query is also doing a select on `posts` table

May be you can try this

```
SELECT 
tbl1.ID AS vendor_id, 
tbl1.post_title AS vendor_name,
COUNT(tbl1.ID) AS featured_stackies
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts tbl1
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as tbl3 ON tbl1.ID=tbl3.post_id AND tbl3.meta_key = 'vendor-ap'           
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as tbl4 ON tbl1.ID=tbl4.post_id AND tbl4.meta_key = 'vendor-as'
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as tbl5 ON tbl1.ID=tbl5.post_id AND tbl5.meta_key = 'vendor-data'
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as tbl6 ON tbl1.ID=tbl6.post_id AND tbl6.meta_key = 'vendor-management'
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as tbl7 ON tbl1.ID=tbl7.post_id AND tbl7.meta_key = 'vendor-sr'
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as tbl8 ON tbl1.ID=tbl8.post_id AND tbl8.meta_key = 'vendor-ae'
WHERE tbl1.post_type = 'vendor-stacks' 
AND tbl1.post_status = 'publish' 
AND tbl1.post_title LIKE '%".$get_query."%'
AND ( tbl1.post_type = 'company-stacks' 
AND tbl1.post_status = 'publish')
AND tbl3.meta_value LIKE CONCAT('%\"',tbl1.ID, '\"%')
OR tbl4.meta_value LIKE CONCAT('%\"',tbl1.ID, '\"%') 
OR tbl5.meta_value LIKE CONCAT('%\"',tbl1.ID, '\"%') 
OR tbl6.meta_value LIKE CONCAT('%\"',tbl1.ID, '\"%') 
OR tbl7.meta_value LIKE CONCAT('%\"',tbl1.ID, '\"%') 
OR tbl8.meta_value LIKE CONCAT('%\"',tbl1.ID, '\"%')

GROUP BY tbl1.ID ORDER BY featured_stackies DESC LIMIT 12 OFFSET 0
```

The above query will make the processing simple as shown below

[image]

Also change the order of the `WHERE` condition based on the below rule

**Optimization 1:**

> which key or primary key in `WHERE` will reduce the data to minimum then bring that comparison to front in the where condition sequence of comparison

For example:
 `tbl1.post_type = 'vendor-stacks' AND tbl1.post_status = 'publish' AND tbl1.post_type = 'company-stacks'`

if `company-stacks` is going to make your 200 date to 10 then change the sequence to

`tbl1.post_type = 'company-stacks' AND tbl1.post_status = 'publish' AND tbl1.post_type = 'vendor-stacks'`

Comment: Great! Thanks for this. I'll update my current query and remove the subquery.